# Recommended way to perform a cast to a smaller type on micro controller in C++

Tags: c++, casting, microcontroller

I am programming for the Arduino Due, which is based on a 32-bits micro controller. I want to read an ADC result register (it has width 32 bits if I am right, but it has a true maximum width of 12 bits, which is the resolution of the ADC), and write it at a given location in an array of integers with width 16 bits.

This works:

```
volatile uint16_t Buf[nchannels];

[... some code...]

void ADC_Handler() {
  for (int i = 0; i < nchannels; i++)
  {
      Buf[i] = (volatile uint16_t) * (ADC->ADC_CDR + channels[i]); // my modification
  }
   FlagConversion = true;
}
```

But using instead a more "explicit" cast does not work:

```
Buf[i] = dynamic_cast<volatile uint16_t *>(ADC->ADC_CDR + channels[i]);
```

Produces:

"error: cannot dynamic_cast '(((RoReg*)1074528336) + ((sizetype)(((unsigned int)channels[i]) * 4)))' (of type 'RoReg* {aka volatile long unsigned int*}') to type 'volatile uint16_t* {aka volatile short unsigned int*}' (target is not pointer or reference to class)"

and similar unclear errors with static and reinterpret casts:

"error: cannot dynamic_cast '(((RoReg*)1074528336) + ((sizetype)(((unsigned int)channels[i]) * 4)))' (of type 'RoReg* {aka volatile long unsigned int*}') to type 'volatile uint16_t* {aka volatile short unsigned int*}' (target is not pointer or reference to class)"

and

"error: invalid conversion from 'volatile uint16_t* {aka volatile short unsigned int*}' to 'uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}"

- Any idea why these more explicit casts fail?
- What would be the best practice here?

Comment: The first code is dereferencing something and then casting the result to an integer. The second code is casting to an pointer without dereferencing. Do you want `Buf[i] = * static_cast<volatile uint16_t *>(ADC->ADC_CDR + channels[i]);` with dereferencing added and using `static_cast` instead?

Comment: It would be good if you come back to your C++ book and read again about casting. `dynamic_cast` applies only for types which have RTTI, so for classes which have at least on virtual method. For integer types it doesn't have seance.

Comment: Ok, thanks :) . So ```Buf[i] = * reinterpret_cast<volatile uint16_t *>(ADC->ADC_CDR + channels[i]);``` works fine, but static and dynamic cast fail (probably because of what @MarekR says). What do you think is best practise to use in this kind of case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 'safe' way to do the cast is to first dereference the pointer to the 32-bit data, then mask out the upper 16 bits of that data item, then `static_cast` the result to your 16-bit destination data:

```cpp
    Buf[i] = static_cast<volatile uint16_t>( *(ADC->ADC_CDR + channels[i]) & 0x0FFFF );
```

It is always best to use the 'simplest' form of cast, and to avoid both C-style casts and `reinterpret_cast` whenever possible. In this case, it makes little sense to cast the pointer, and it is *much* safer and simpler to convert/cast the data itself.

Actually, the masking with `0x0FFFF` is, strictly speaking, entirely unnecessary and superfluous. However, it makes it clear to any future reader of your code that you do, indeed, know what you're doing!

Comment: A small question @AdrianMole : why write 0x0FFFF instead of 0xFFFF ? Is it to make sure we remember that we cut?

Comment: @Zorglub29 I just like to add at least one leading zero to make it clear that ***I*** know what I'm doing. Other folks would write the full 32 bits: `0x0000FFFF` and still others will omit the leading zero. It's simply a question of style/taste.